# How to add text on image in ReactJS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS. Today I decided to create my own blog. Header needs image with some text. And when trying to add text on image, text slides down. I need to my text position to be at center

[image] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbbMK.jpg)

Code:

Header.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import './header.scss'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <div className = "head-text">
        <div className = "head-image">
          <img src = {require ('../ images / Header.png')} alt = "Freedom Blog" />
        </div>
          <h3> Welcome to my Blog </h3>
          <p> FREEEEDOM </p>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}


export default Header;
```

Header.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import './index.scss'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS files are empty, so I didn't add them.

Answer (score 5):

You can add text on an image using CSS absolute positioning.
Can read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

add CSS class to the text you want to display on the image for example :

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <div className = "head-text">
        <div className = "head-image">
          <img src = {require ('../ images / Header.png')} alt = "Freedom Blog" />
        </div>
          <div class='text-on-image'>
             <h3> Welcome to my Blog </h3>
             <p> FREEEEDOM </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Then in header.css:

```
.head-text {
   position: relative;
}
.text-on-image {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15%;
}
```

This will place the text on the bottom center of the image.

The div which has position relative is the div by which the absolute positioned (`text-on-image`) `right,left,bottom` properties are determined by.

So for example a `bottom:10px` will make the `text-on-image` place it self 10px above the bottom part of the div which has `position: relative`

Play with the CSS absolute position values in order to place it where you want.
more examples  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
<header>
  <img src = {require ('../ images / Header.png')} alt = "Freedom Blog" />
  <h3> Welcome to my Blog </h3>
  <p> FREEEEDOM </p>
</header>
```

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className = "head-text">
        <div className = "head-image">
          <img src = {require ('../ images / Header.png')} alt = "Freedom Blog" />
        </div>
        <div className="center__text">
          <h3> Welcome to my Blog </h3>
          <p> FREEEEDOM </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

You can do it like this

```
.head-text{
position: relative;
color: white;
```

color mention above will be the color of your text

```
.center__text{
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Now your text will appear in center of your image

Answer (score 0):

if you want hadle text on image please following this code (make tailwindcss):

```
<Div className="relative flex flex-row-reverse justify-between items-center rounded-3xl">
    <Img
      src="./sky.webp"
      className="absolute w-full h-full top-0 left-0 object-cover rounded-3xl bg-transparent"
    />
    <Span
      className=" rounded-[21.9px]  flex flx-row justify-center items-center w-full h-full text-[150px]  dark:bg-darkBackground"
      style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}
    >
      Let's Talk
    </Span>
  </Div>
```

you can delete **mixBlendMode**